# Accessing default MPM prefork values in Ubuntu(debian based architecture) vs CentOS (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, redhat, mpm-prefork, mpm-event

I was trying to list the MPM prefork default configuration values in apache web server. In ubuntu, apache web server, I could access the values inside `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf` file. But in CentOS, I couldn't find the similar file anywhere. By following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664056/prefork-mpm-configuration-not-in-httpd-conf) I found out details can be found in the file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf` but 'there is nothing except loading the module'. Is there any way for me to access/list the default values loaded for the MPM configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep -r MinSpareServers /etc/httpd`, and so on. If you don't find the directives there, then they're not set in the configuration, so they're at their default values.

Comment: Do you know any reason why both behaves differently? Ex. in ubuntu values are loaded in the mpm_prefork.conf file, while its left to default in CentOS systems ?

Comment: No particular reason. Different distros package things differently.